# Как в СУБД Firebird в анонимном блоке(execute block) использовать input?

Tags: sql, firebird

Есть несколько скриптов,

один главный который должен вызвать другой скрипт в зависимости от условия.

main.sql

```
execute block
declare variable uslovie integer = 0;
as
begin
  select ... into :uslovie; -- в переменной содержится результат запроса
  if (:uslovie = 1) 
  then input script_1.sql; -- как выполнит скрипт?
end
```

Если "input script_1.sql" поставить в начало или в конец файла вне анонимного блока он выполнится.

Провал обернуть его в "execute statement" не получилось.

Answer (score 1):

`input` - это не команда SQL, она не может находиться внутри PSQL-блока.

`input`, также как и, например, `set term` - команда среды исполнения. Ее поддерживает программа isql (возможно и IBExpert), но сам Firebird о ней ничего не знает и выполнить не может.